# Raspberry Pi 3B is heating up very quick and PUTTY cannot connect. Is it gone?

Tags: temperature

I cannot connect anymore to Raspi using PUTTY for a few hours. Short before I saw during boot time some mmc1 110 errors and a undervoltage sign on the screen.

At the same time, the temperature of the device is so high I cannot touch it (not before!).

I was trying some led configuration. Is it possible that a piece of copper wire caused a shortcut on the board with this outcome?

Comment: Sounds like you've shorted something. Time to buy a new Pi.

Comment: Hmm, I hoped that was not neccessary, but was afraid...Can I find my scripts on the SD card?

Comment: The SD card will probably be okay.  You will need to mount the file system on another Linux machine (or Pi).

Comment: `some mmc1 110 errors` - whatever they are, that could also mean your data is at least partially corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Any Raspberry where only the red LED lights up and any part of it gets too hot to touch very quickly is dead. The fix costs £35.

What you need to understand is how you killed it. What part of the hardware did you abuse or your next Raspberry is going to suffer the exact same fate.

Raspberries are not "hot-pluggable". You can insert USB & HDMI devices with the power on (as those interfaces support it). But everything else, camera, screen, I²C, SPI, serial should only be connected with the power off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My Py was not "hot-plugged". The red led is ON and at boottime I see some green Led-flashes, but it never reaches the end of the bootproces. I get 4 MMC1 110 error) and then tries toboot again. In the meantime 1 or 2 minutes later one cannot touch the processor without burning himself.
So, this extreme behaviour is new and reason for me (after consulting StackExchangeForum) to throw it away and buy a new one.
Robavh

Comment: I think that I shortcutted the Pi with some metal tools hanging around on my desk. Not advisaable when working with a unprotected board. :-(